# Ncover not covering the code in child process of the test.dll (which is started using Process.start) in C#

Tags: c#, ncover

I want to get coverage of let's say CoverageTarget.dll.

I have a test.dll to run the nunit tests, which starts a child process childTestApp.exe(which tests some of the code in CoverageTarget.dll) using the Process.Start method in the process of testing.

in the results i am not able to see the code covered by the childTestApp.exe.

this is may be expected behavior,but 
is there any way/tool i can get the code covered in the testApp.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the //pm argument (http://docs.ncover.com/ref/3-0/ncover-console/command-line/profiling-options#pm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
//PM argument takes one process name , is there a way to give more processes for this argument?
now i have to run the coverage separately for each process.

Comment: NCover 3.4 lets you give more than one process name